# Location of Freeciv Rule Files on Linux

Tags: linux, freeciv

Where are the rule files located on the Linux filesystem for Freeciv? I appreciate any and all help.

Answer (score 1):

On my system the ruleset files are found at /usr/share/freeciv/RULESETNAME/SUBJECT.ruleset, where RULESETNAME is civ1, civ2, civ2civ3, classic, ..., and SUBJECT is buildings, cities, units, terrain, ...

Comment: By default this is where they're put, but it's possible for a distro to specify some other location, and if you're compiling Freeciv yourself (rather than using packages), it'll default to `/usr/local/share/freecive/RULESETNAME/`.

Answer (score 0):

Install [`locate`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/locate.1.html) and use

```
locate .ruleset
```

to find all files with `.ruleset` in their names.
Freeciv ruleset files use this extension, and nothing else that I know of does.

Comment: Hey @reinierpost, could you elaborate on this? A brief summary of what this is supposed to do and even a link to a guide on installing the "locate" function would go a long to beef up your answer.

Comment: How to install it is distribution specific. I've added a few words on what this does.